# How to setup Symfony form for many to many relationship with add only, no edit or delete

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a many to many relationships setup between 2 entities, User and Course. I have join table UserCourse for the relationship that has a extra fields for the start date and a expiry date. If I setup as a ManyToMany relationship in Doctrine I can create an EntityTypeform that allow adding and deleting courses from a user, but, I cannot get it to set the UserCourse expiry which needs to be set using the date the UserCourse record is created + a subScriptionExpiry term value from the Course entity (a string like "+1 year"). I tried via PrePersist but it isn't triggered when the collection is updated.

```php
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Course", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="course_user",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $courses;
```

```php
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course")
 */
class Course

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="users")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="subscription_expiry", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subscriptionExpiry;
```

```
/**
 * CourseUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course_user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class CourseUser
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="expiry", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $expiry;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
      */
    public function updateExpiry()
    {
        $this->expiry = new DateTime($this->getCourse()->getSubscriptionExpiry());
    }
```

```php
// UserController Create form
$form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
...
        return $this->render('user/editb.html.twig', [
            'userForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
```

```php
// UserFormType
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...) // some user fields
            ->add('courses', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Course::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Courses',
                'query_builder' => function(CourseRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createIsActiveQueryBuilder();
                }
            ])
        ;
```

```
{{ form_start(userForm) }}
...
{{ form_row(userForm.courses) }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate>Save</button>

{{ form_end(userForm) }}
```

[image: screenshot]

If I set it up as a OneToMany/ManyToOne I can create a CollectionType embedded form, but I need to disallow editing existing UserCourse records and the CollectionType displays the Course field of the UserCourse records as select fields where the course can be changed.

```php
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     *  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CourseUser", mappedBy="user", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $userCourses;
```

```php
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course")
 */
class Course

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CourseUser", mappedBy="course", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $courseUsers;
```

```php
// UserFormType
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...) // some user fields
            ->add('userCourses',CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => UserCourseEmbeddedForm::class,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
        ;
```

```php
// UserCourseEmbeddedForm
        $builder
            ->add('course', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Course::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(CourseRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createIsActiveQueryBuilder();
                }
            ])
```

```
{{ form_start(userForm) }}
...
<h3>Courses</h3>
<div class="row js-user-course-wrapper"
     data-prototype="{{ form_widget(userForm.userCourses.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
     data-index="{{ userForm.userCourses|length }}"
>
    {% for userCourseForm in userForm.userCourses %}
        <div class="col-xs-4 js-user-course-item">
            {{ form_errors(userCourseForm) }}
            {{ form_row(userCourseForm.course) }}
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="#" class="js-user-course-add">
        <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>
        Add Another Course
    </a>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate>Save</button>

{{ form_end(userForm) }}
```

The code for add course is in another template and creates an empty form via the form definition prototype.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to fix these issues? Or a better way to do the data model or forms to make this work more seamlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your latter approach (ManyToOne/OneToMany), use css to mark the drop-down boxes as disabled (in the embedded form, use `'attr' => ['disabled' => true]`, then enable newly rendered `select` items using javascript. You may also want to mark `'allowDelete' => false` in your UserFormType, otherwise you may need to re-enable all `select` items upon form submission.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to just enable the drop-down using the inspect element if you do it that way?

Comment: What do you mean by "enable newly rendered select items using javascript"? are you referring to the "Add Another Course" form?

Comment: @CharlotteMoller - presumably you have some javascript code that runs when you click "Add Another Course" that creates a new `select` element with course options. Since you will have these marked as `disabled` per my suggestion, you will then have to remove the the disabled attribute for the newly rendered element.

Comment: @LiamRoels - I don't know what the "inspect element" is that you mention?

Comment: @ehymel if someone would just change the html/css in the browser he is using and enable the dropdown to select what he wants. Then he could sumbit the form with some values you didn't want to see submitted. It's a security issue I guess

Comment: @ehymel with that I just mean that css isn't the correct solution here...

Comment: @LiamRoels - good point, this is easy to circumvent. Some back end validation could check for this I suppose. I don't know of any other suggestion.

Comment: @LiamRoels your suggestions work, tx! I'd rather display the selected courses as text rather than a disabled select box which isn't that visually appealing. Do the assigned course embedded forms have to be select elements for the processing on form submission to work? I also need to figure out how to only display unassigned courses in the "Add Another Course" form, any suggestions?